# Links are visible far past the top margin of the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was experimenting dragging the page up as far as it would go for no apparent reason (I have rubber-band scrolling), and I noticed this:

[image]

I couldn't reproduce it on any other site that I tried.

Comment: Which browser/OS is this? I can't find anything in the page code which would do that. (Not that it isn't there; but I haven't found it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified the code to replace `top: -200px` with `text-indent: -999em;` which is our "standard" way of hiding things on other DOM elements across the site. This will be live in the next prod build.

Answer (score 0):

Those labels are attached to the buttons on the top bar and assigned the CSS class `hidden-text`. Despite the name, they are not actually hidden--they're just positioned above the top of the page:

```
.topbar .hidden-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
}
```

This seems like a strange decision, but all the other SE sites I've checked do the top bar the same way, so I suppose there's a reason for it.